# catching 10 fish: a combinatorics question

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose that 10 fish are caught at a lake that contains 5 distinct types of fish. among the 10 fish at least 2 are trout. also, it is given that all 5 different types of fishes have been caught at least once.
How many different outcomes are possible, where an outcome specifies the numbers of caught fish of each of the 5 types
**my attempt:**
let $(x_1+1),(x_2+1),(x_3+1),(x_4+1) $ represent the numbers of fish caught of type 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively. let $(x_5+2)$ represent the number of trout fishes caught.
then it is given that $(x_1+1)+(x_2+1)+(x_3+1)+(x_4+1)+(x_5+2) = 10$
$=>x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 = 4$, where $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4,x_5$ are non-negative integers.
=> the total number of outcomes are $\binom{4+5-1}{5-1} = \binom{8}{4} = 70$, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, your work is correct.

Comment: It is correct if I am not missing anything

Comment: Where did the $8$ come from?

Comment: @Air Mike 8=4+5-1. The last line comes from a stars-and-bars argument.